# Android keyboard app, with undo

Tags: gratis, android, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I am perfectly happy with Swiftkey, for the following reasons:

- I can see numbers as well as letters, without having to switch views
- It learns my most frequent words and offers them first as suggestions (and it doesn’t seem to store passwords, or anything entered in browser incognito mode)
- It also seems to learn frequently used phrases, so that after I enter one word, it quite will predicts what the next will be, sometimes completing an entire sentence

So far, so excellent, ***BUT***, I simply cannot accept that it does not have an undo key for its autocorrect. If I enter technical terms or parts of URLs, it “helpfully” corrects them. I would expect pressing backspace to tell it “look, dude, I know what I meant there, so please accept that” – but it does not.

So, can anyone recommend a keyboard with the above features, ***PLUS*** undo?

Additional features would be nice, but are not needed. I do not do the FaceTweet, so do not need any social media enhancements or emojii.  Hmmm, as list of frequently phrases would be “nice to have”, but is not “must have”.

Comment: Hmmm Swiftkey in conjunction with Inputting+ might do the trick   http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/undo-redo-text-android-and-more/

Comment: Hacker's Keyboard lets you do ctrl z/ ctrl shift z undo/redo. Not a single button and undoes more than the last correction. In general a bit rough for general use. Probably not what you're looking for. (dictionary installed separately)

Answer (score -1):

Why not [turn off autocorrect in Swiftkey](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/201592021-How-do-I-turn-off-SwiftKey-Auto-Insert-Predictions-)?

Comment: Welcome aboard. Thanks for the ***comment***, which is ***not*** an answer (I will not downvote you, but others might; given your profile you ought to know better). I want to have auto-correct and it is usually a good thing. I just want the ability to reject an auto-correct from time to time.

Comment: Based on your question, it seemed like a solution. However, if you do not wish to turn off autocorrect, it may not be your solution. Is there a way to convert an answer to comment?

Comment: As far as I know, you woudl have to delete the anwwer and submit a comment